# imagemagic tile numbering in windows batch

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick

The following snipet works fine and creates tiles in the /sliced subfolder.

```
FOR %%a in (C:\someFolder\*.png) DO (
  ECHO Processing file: "%%~nxa"    
  convert %%a -crop 3x3@  +repage  +adjoin  %~dp0\sliced\%%~na.png
)
```

However the numbering of the resulting tiles are ugly. Its in the following form: FileName-0.png, FileName-1.png,

I would like to make it start from 1 and use an underscore, like: FileName_1.png, FileName_2.png, 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not in a position to test this till later, but I think you can set the scene number to 1 like this:

```
convert image.jpg -crop ... -scene 1 ...
```

and that should make the numbering start at 1 rather than 0.

Also, if you put `%d` in your output filename, it will put the scene number in there, so you probably want

```
convert image.jpg -crop ... -scene 1 ... file_%d.jpg
```

you may need to double up the percent signs in Windows awful batch language, or maybe put a caret `^` in front of it. I think it's the caret you need...

Here is an example of chopping up a gray image of 9x9 pixels into tiles:

```
convert xc:gray[9x9] -crop 3x3@ -scene 23 +repage file_%d.png
```

**Resulting files**

```
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  263  4 Oct 11:18 file_23.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  263  4 Oct 11:18 file_24.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  263  4 Oct 11:18 file_25.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  263  4 Oct 11:18 file_26.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  263  4 Oct 11:18 file_27.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  263  4 Oct 11:18 file_28.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  263  4 Oct 11:18 file_29.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  263  4 Oct 11:18 file_30.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  263  4 Oct 11:18 file_31.png
```

If you want the scene numbers zero-padded, use `%04d` for example:

```
convert xc:gray[9x9] -crop 3x3@ -scene 23 +repage file_%04d.png
```

**Resulting files**

```
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  263  4 Oct 11:21 file_0023.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  263  4 Oct 11:21 file_0024.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  263  4 Oct 11:21 file_0025.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  263  4 Oct 11:21 file_0026.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  263  4 Oct 11:21 file_0027.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  263  4 Oct 11:21 file_0028.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  263  4 Oct 11:21 file_0029.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  263  4 Oct 11:21 file_0030.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  263  4 Oct 11:21 file_0031.png
```

In fact, you can probably avoid the whole ugly `for loop`, delayed expansion, double-percent, exclamation-mark mess of Windows by using `mogrify` like this:

```
mogrify -crop 3x3@ -scene 34 -path sliced *png
```

which, if you have files called `a.png` and `b.png` in your current directory will result in:

```
sliced/a-34.png
sliced/a-35.png
sliced/a-36.png
sliced/a-37.png
sliced/a-38.png
sliced/a-39.png
sliced/a-40.png
sliced/a-41.png
sliced/a-42.png
sliced/b-34.png
sliced/b-35.png
sliced/b-36.png
sliced/b-37.png
sliced/b-38.png
sliced/b-39.png
sliced/b-40.png
sliced/b-41.png
sliced/b-42.png
```

I don't think you can achieve the underscore and zero-padding with `mogrify` though. But you can still use `convert` like I demonstrated at the start of my answer.

In Windows, you may need to double up on the percent signs, or escape with a caret `^` - not sure of the mad syntax there.

Comment: Inside batch files `%%` is required to pass a single `%` to the command line, yes.

Comment: Perfect. Based on the answer this is what I came up with:

`@ECHO OFF
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (C:\localhost\peopletest\branches\dev\design\Matrices\*.png) do (  
  echo processing file: "%%~nxa"
convert %%a -crop 3x3@ +repage -scene 1 +adjoin %~dp0sliced\%%~na_%%02d.png
)
PAUSE`

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=1
for %%a in (C:\someFolder\*.png) do (
  echo processing file: !count!: "%%~nxa"    
  convert %%a -crop 3x3@ +repage +adjoin %~dp0sliced\%%~na_!count!.png
  set /a count+=1
)
```

With leading zeros, actually is 3 digits number, change `!lz:~-3!` to `!lz:~-4!` if you need 4 digits number

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=1
for %%a in (C:\someFolder\*.png) do (
  set lz=0000!count!
  echo processing file: !lz:~-3!: "%%~nxa"    
  convert %%a -crop 3x3@ +repage +adjoin %~dp0sliced\%%~na_!lz:~-3!.png
  set /a count+=1
)
```